# When using wireless triggers is it best to use a different wireless shutter release system?

Tags: shutter-release, wireless-flash, wireless-triggers

I am wondering which way is better:

1. Use a trigger system with multiple receivers, including one on the camera to control the shutter
2. Use a separate trigger/shutter system and have the camera fire the flashes on another wireless system, from the hot shoe etc.

I currently own the Pixel Pro 'Pawn' Trigger and Receiver and find them excellent, even though they don't do TTL but that's not a huge issue right now.

I was looking to get another couple of receivers and maybe use one as the shutter release on the camera but then I was looking at the Pixel TW-282 remote control. Obviously the remote control has more functionality but since that is not in the scope of the question it doesn't matter all that much for the purpose of this question.

**This question is all about timing; leaving Hi-Speed Sync aside will it be more accurate to use option 2, or does it matter, to make sure to have the flashes fire at the exact time they are meant to and not before or after.**

I can't determine if using the remote for the 'Pawn' system (option 1) will have the flashes fire prematurely etc.

(While doing a self portrait I forgot to turn off auto focus on the lens which had the camera re-focus but fire the flashes before the shot and it got me thinking about this.)

Comment: If you're worried about triggering the flash too early (because it's simultaneous with the shutter release) then you could use separate channels.

Comment: Well the point of Option 1 is that it will be the same trigger, there is only one. Whereas in option 2 there is two separate systems. Your comment, while valid and obviously useful and correct, doesn't apply and defeats the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confident that it doesn't matter. The sync max speed on your camera is when the shutter is completely open. A flash is typically 1/2000th or less. Delaying it a few milliseconds is not a problem.

None of this stuff is "exact" timing.

Many of the wireless trigger systems use two channels, one for the shutter and the second, a "relay" for the strobes, as their nomal operating procedure.